# Count down timer, with a dynamic date

Tags: javascript, html, magento-1.9

I am coding for a count down timer which will reset evry morning at 11 am, and date i am calling is dynamic means date will change daily. 
Some how i have coded correctly it somwtimes show correct countdown but oftenly it shows NAN NAN when i randomly check it on windows system.
[image]

Below is my code -

```
<div class="countdown">
    <span>DEAL TIME LEFT : </span>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
<script>

    var currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    var day = currentDate.getDate();
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    //alert(year);
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date(day+" "+month+" "+year+",  11:00:00").getTime();

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

        // Get todays date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + " : "
    + minutes + " : " + seconds;

        // If the count down is over, write some text 
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        }
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Even I have checked, **alert(day),alert(month), alert(year)** All these are correct but still I am getting **"NAN, NAN" error**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue here

```
var countDownDate = new Date(day+" "+month+" "+year+",  11:00:00").getTime();
```

The `Date` constructor can't parse your string and `.getTime()` return `NaN`.

Instead of using string. You can use the other parameters of the `Date` constructor .

> new Date(year, month[, date[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[,
>   milliseconds]]]]]);

```
var countDownDate = new Date(year, month, day,11).getTime();
```

```html
<div class="countdown">
<span>DEAL TIME LEFT : </span>
<p id="demo"></p>

</div>
<script>

var currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var day = currentDate.getDate();
var month = currentDate.getMonth() ;
var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
 //alert(year);
// Set the date we're counting down to

var countDownDate = new Date(year, month, day,11).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + " : "
    + minutes + " : " + seconds;

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: That will give the wrong month, you still have `var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;`. You can't see it because you're only looking at the hours. ;-)

Comment: @RobG - pls elaborate, I didn understand where I am still wrong ?

Comment: @Khushbu_sipl—this creates a date, gets the month, adds 1, then creates another date using the +1 month. It will likely show what appears to be the correct time because the month isn't part of the result, but it still creates an incorrect date. I've posted an answer, more as an example of how to go about it than answer your specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to count down to 11 am and if it's after 11, to 11 am tomorrow.

The following creates an end date that is at 11:00 today or, if after, 11:00 tomorrow. It then formats the time remaining. Then there's a timer to call it every second, just after the next full second so it doesn't drift.

It only creates one date and shows how to add a day and set it to a specific time.

Hopefully the comments are sufficient.

```js
function showRemaining() {
  var endDate = new Date();

  // If after 1100, add a day
  if (endDate.getHours() > 11) {   
    endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 1);
  }
  // Set time to 11am;
  endDate.setHours(11,0,0,0);

  // Get seconds from now to end
  var diff = Math.ceil((endDate - Date.now())/1000);

  // Show time as h:mm:ss
  return ( (diff/3.6e3|0) + ':' +
           ('0'+((diff%3.6e3)/60|0)).slice(-2) + ':' +
           ('0'+(diff%60)).slice(-2)
         );
}
 
// Run every second just after next full second
(function timer() {
    console.log(showRemaining());
    var lag = 1020 - (Date.now()%1000)
    setTimeout(timer, lag);
}());
```

Comment: thanx RobG :) for your rapid replay